ulタグの中に入った子要素li要素を画面の両端に寄せたい
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TOTALLY</title>
    <meta name="description" content="テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- googleフォントでフォントを選んでみましょう！ -->

</head>
<header>
    <section class="header">
        <div class="headerlogo">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="headerlist">
            <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ALL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NEW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VINTAGE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CATEGORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="login">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="totallycontents">
            <div class="totally">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h1>TOTALLY Short Sleeve Shirt</h1>
                <p>テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト<br>テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト<br>テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト<br>テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト<br>テキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキストテキスト<br>テキストテキストテキスト</p>
                <p>￥9,999 +tax</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </section>
</header>

<body></body>
<footer></footer>

@charset "UTF-8";

#header {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
}


.headerlogo {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.headerlogo img {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.headerlist {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 20px;
}

.login ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 20px;
}

.totallycontents {
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
}

.totally img {
    width: 400px;
}

.info {

}


「両端に寄せる」とはどういう意味でしょうか。均等割付のことですか?

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

質問タイトル「ulタグの中に入った子要素li要素を画面の両端に寄せたい」と提供されている HTML から考えると、以下ナビメニュー部分の青枠部分を左寄せ、緑枠部分を右寄せしたいということですかね？

もしそうであれば、css の headerlist に justify-content: space-between; を追加することで実現できます。
.headerlist {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    /* 以下追加 */
    justify-content: space-between;
}

修正後の画面は、以下となります。

justify-content で配置方法を調整できます。space-between 以外のオプションもあるので、詳細は、以下を確認ください。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content


様々な意見くださりありがとうございます！無事解決しました！今後も皆さんの意見いただきプログラミング頑張ってまいります
